# Knockout custom binding for FullCalendar v4

Tags: knockout.js, fullcalendar-4

I'm hoping someone experienced with Knockout custom bindings can help me create one for FullCalendar V4.
I have never created one before and I'm a little surprised no one has or hasn't shared it for others.
Here's what I have so far:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fullCalendar = {
    init: function(element) {
        var calendarEl = $(element);
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
            defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
            defaultDate: '2019-06-07',
            header: {
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            },
            events: viewModel.array1()
        });
    }
}
```

I also have a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/jjfrick/pen/mdyPmev?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Calendar function requires an HTML element, you can directly pass the one provided by the Init parameters. After creating calendar, you need to render. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.fullCalendar = {
    init: function(element) {
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(element, {
            plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
            defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
            defaultDate: '2019-06-07',
            header: {
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            },
            events: viewModel.array1()
        });
      calendar.render(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I need to figure out how to add the "update" portion to the binding.